# STM32 PWM signal keeps dropping to zero at random

Tags: stm32, pwm, vibration-motor

I'm working with two [DRV2605L](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv2605l.pdf?ts=1683119643574&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) vibration motor drivers, both set up to control an LRA motor with a PWM signal from an STM32L552ZET6Q microcontroller. The PWM signal goes through a resistor voltage divider, bringing the signal down to prevent an odd glitch I discovered, where having a PWM value too high causes the output to the LRA motor to get stuck until power cycled.

[image: PWM to LRA Driver voltage divider]

The PWM signals come from the L5's timer 1, channels 1 & 2. Additionally, there are three servo motors attached to timer 3, channels 1, 2 & 3. Timer 1's configuration can be seen below:

[image: Timer 1 configuration for PWM output to LRA driver]

And here is the CubeMX generated code, in case that's preferable:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 1099;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 99;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakAFMode = TIM_BREAK_AFMODE_INPUT;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2AFMode = TIM_BREAK_AFMODE_INPUT;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

The device is mostly working as intended, but there's one problem that has persisted; at random intervals, the PWM signal coming from the L5 to the DRV's PWM input pin will randomly drop to zero, then return to its previous value without issue. What's more, this only happens with the DRV unit I'm explicitly controlling the PWM signal of at a given moment; Both PWM channels can exhibit this behaviour, but only one at a time.

the LRA motor is located on a remote board and shares this board with an IMU unit. The IMU is connected to the STM32 via UART, translated to RS232 while crossing the cable that connects the main board and remote board, and back again once it exits the cable. I've been testing with a logic analyzer to see if the odd behaviour in the PWM signal was consistent with something on the UART bus, but I haven't found any evidence of that link yet. I'm now having trouble finding the odd PWM behaviour in the logic analyzer, though I did see brief glimpses of it on an oscilloscope.

I'm reasonably sure I can rule out firmware as the issue, at least to a point; I wrote in the program to default to a specific value if the values the microcontroller received were outside certain parameters, and it doesn't make a difference so far. Below is the code that determines which driver/PWM channel to adjust:

```
void writeHapticPWM()
{
    //int value = 0;
    if((((data < 25) || (data > 65))) || (((data >= 25) && (data <= 65)) && (data % 5 != 0)))
    {
        data =  65;
    }
    switch(unit)
    {
    case(0x00):
            //value = drvM;
            LRA1->status = DRV2605_ACTIVE;
            LRA2->status = DRV2605_STANDBY;
            //smoothHaptics(LRA2, 65);
            //smoothHaptics(LRA1, data);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA2, 65);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA1, data);
            break;
    case(0x01):

            LRA2->status = DRV2605_ACTIVE;
            LRA1->status = DRV2605_STANDBY;
            //smoothHaptics(LRA1, 65);
            //smoothHaptics(LRA2, data);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA1, 65);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA2, data);
            break;
    case(0x02):
            //smoothHaptics(LRA1, 65);
            //smoothHaptics(LRA2, 65);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA1, 65);
            DRV2605_PWM_Output(LRA2, 65);
            LRA1->status = DRV2605_STANDBY;
            LRA2->status = DRV2605_STANDBY;
    default:
        return;
    }
    usb_ACK();
    //testUSB();
}
```

And here is the code that adjusts the PWM signal:

```
void DRV2605_PWM_Output(struct DRV *drv, int output)
{
    TIM_HandleTypeDef *Timer = drv->timer;
    uint32_t channel = drv->channel;
    switch(channel)
    {
    case(TIM_CHANNEL_1):
        Timer->Instance->CCR1 = output;
        drv->currentPosition = output;
        break;
    case(TIM_CHANNEL_2):
        Timer->Instance->CCR2 = output;
        drv->currentPosition = output;
        break;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I considered the possibility that I was overdriving the DRV2605L, but that doesn't seem to be the case either. All evidence I have points to the PWM signal coming from the STM32 dropping to nothing for a brief moment before returning to normal.

I've tried researching this problem and apparently people who have encountered similar issues have fixed it by enabled the auto-reload preload bit, but that hasn't worked so far. Does anyone have any other ideas for what could cause a PWM signal from a microcontroller, STM32 or otherwise, that could cause this behaviour?

edit: At Rokta's suggestion, I checked the APRE & OC1PE values in the TIM1 SFR, in debug mode. Both of them are 0x1, as seen in the image below.

[image: TIM1 SFR]

Comment: Which auto-reload did you try to enable? Global auto-reload (ARPE in TIM1_CR1 register) or specific one for your PWM channel (OC1PE in TIM1_CCMR1 register).

Comment: @Rokta I didn't even know there was a channel-specific one. The one I enabled via CUBEMX was under TIM1's parameter settings, named auto-reload preload. You can see it in the image from cubeMX I posted. Is it possible to see that register without running debug? Not a problem if I can't, I'm just curious.

Comment: No idea what could be the problem then unless you start/stop timer somewhere in your code. Maybe you could "fix" this problem by inverting PWM signal idle state to see if value will be too low now (if you can tolerate too low values).

Comment: @Rokta Okay, I've made some progress, and *somehow* (I'm still not sure if this is true or how), it seems that the USB communications might be the problem. Again, still testing and researching, but the problem only occurs when I'm sending a constant stream of instructions on what the PWM duty cycle should be, even if those instructions are to keep the signal the exact same. I even have lines of code meant to stop the duty cycle from changing from x to y if x = y.